# Using voltage dependent capacitor in PID tuning?

Tags: capacitor, pid-controller

[Changes in capacitance of some types of MLCC with applied voltage](https://www.digikey.com/Site/Global/Layouts/DownloadPdf.ashx?pdfUrl=863968494F2E4E13BBEA65B55A358443) is a well known phenomenon. Changes can be quite considerable eg -50%

Has anyone ever tried using this effect to fine tune the I term in a PID controller? We need an easily tunable ultra low noise circuit

Comment: Is "ultra low noise" compatible with "MLCC acting as piezoelectric microphone"?

Comment: I've often mused about the possibility of a low frequency varactor, perhaps for an AM radio, using MLCCs. Needless to say, not done any experiments. Try it. You might bear in mind that in a PID controller, you might want a large voltage swing on your capacitor, which would give you a very non-linear response, and so possibly defeat the object of your tuning it. Low resistance CMOS switches selecting various caps would be a linear way of altering the tuning.

Comment: @bobflux It will all be in a temperature controlled environment. One problem at a time...

Comment: Consider the specs you want, and mock up a prototype to see if it fits the bill. (Not sure how you are going to separate the "tuning" voltage from the integration voltage, unless you are integrating by pulse counting the output of a VCO. In which case any VCO would do)

Comment: Those same capacitors have horrible dielectric absorption and hysteresis. A modern PID implementation would probably be done digitally anyway.

Comment: @KevinWhite Maybe, but we would need full 24 resolution

Comment: @DirkBruere - getting 24 bits in the numerical calculation is easy. Getting more than about 20 bits of ADC conversion is not. But neither is getting >120dB dynamic range in analog. Especially as that would demand large signal swings that would go against using the voltage dependency of the capacitor as a tuning element. What is your dynamic range?

Comment: @KevinWhite At present our balance resolves to 1 part in 20 million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Has anyone ever tried using this effect to fine tune the I term in a
> PID controller? We need an easily tunable ultra low noise circuit.*

Considering that the integrator is naturally trying to accumulate a DC voltage, I think this would be a bad idea. The accumulation of the DC voltage (i.e. the normal working of an integrator) will disturb the capacitance value and, make this a bad idea IMHO. Then, if you could somehow overcome that (not-inconsiderable) problem, how would you apply a tuning voltage to the capacitor that didn't upset the natural and expected voltage output of the integrator?

No, it sounds like a bad idea to me.

The only working area for this idea is when trying to modify an AC signal because the DC level is of no-importance. Even then, you have to be mindful of the peak AC voltages because they would distort waveforms asymmetrically and this might be a problem.

It's a solution waiting for a problem I suspect but, none of the above are suitable.